# How to the call the methods of an Activity from broadcast receiver once the app is quitted?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, static-members

I want to call the activity method from broadcast receiver onReceive method which will be called once the alarm gets triggered.

**Below is my Home Activity code snippet**

```
 public class HomeActivity extends Activity{
         public static HomeActivity mHomeActivity = null;

         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         }


         public void startLocationReporting(){
           ...........//Logic to start the location reporting
         }

         public void stopLocationReporting(){
           ...........//Logic to stopthe location reporting
         }
    }
```

**Below Broadcast receiver will be triggered based on the alarm we configured**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       // Here context is application context not an HomeActivity instance

       //Below code works fine when the app is in foreground 
       if (HomeActivity.mHomeActivity != null) {
            HomeActivity.mHomeActivity.startLocationReporting();
       }

       //Static references are cleared once the app quits. 
       //How to start location reporting when the app is quitted
    }
}
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

> How to the call the methods of an Activity from broadcast receiver
>   once the app is quited?

Calling methods from class by creating object of class which extends `Activity` class will cause following major issues:

**1.** `token android.os.BinderProxy@43756de8 is not valid; is your activity running?`  when trying to accessing any service using Activity context with is not running

**2.** `NullPointerException` when accessing views in calling methods.

or may other issues are also possible...

Try to implement logic using IntentService :

**A.** Create separate class with `startLocationReporting` and `stopLocationReporting` by passing all required parameters.
  *By doing this you will access both methods from Activity or from any other components*

**B.** Create a `IntentService` for doing task and start it when `onReceive` method called. *By this application will do long running task in background so call `startLocationReporting` and `stopLocationReporting` by passing all required parameters in IntentService*

Comment: Already I have decoupled most of the things. From Home Activity I am just checking GPS and calling Location, User Activity tracking and all. Just calling different class code inside that start method. But I think there place which require activity context rather than application context. Even calling from broadcast receiver also wont work out i guess. Please share me your thoughts

Comment: @MVignesh: But you are trying to call methods from Activity which is not running so i think app will not work with current logic you should change way of calling methods

Comment: How to change this. Can u please share the code structure similar to my question.

Comment: @MVignesh: already told in my answer try it in same way if getting any issue in understanding my answer or in implementation then let me know